# UIAlertView with 3 buttons hides message in landscape mode

Tags: hide, message, uialertview, landscape

My UIAlertView has a message and 3 buttons, my problem is the alert view display normally in portrait but it hides message in landscape mode as below screenshots. How to make the message appears? Thanks in advance.

[image: Portrait mode]
[image: Landscape]

Comment: I tried to edit alert view frame and message frame as well not no luck...hix

Comment: Same problem here, did you find a solution?

Comment: I did not find out a solution yet :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I too got same problem,

But I solved this, with a small change. like add `"\n\n"` at the end of `Title` in the `alertView`

This is not a correct solution. but this will rectify that problem some what.

*Note : The Title and the Message should be of one line text.

Thanks,

Satya

Comment: I tried you trick, but it just can display one row of message, It cause the message I would like to display in French is clipped.

Answer (score 1):

By merging the Title String into the Message String you can fit two lines of landscaped text.  Localization wise, this is a problem for many of us so I'm going to file a bug with Apple as it appears we aren't the only ones dealing with this problem.

Note: Any LS_ strings in my system are referenced from the Localizable.strings file.

So I went from:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"LS_Prompt_RateApp_Title", NULL)
                                                        message:(@"LS_Prompt_RateApp_Message", NULL)
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"LS_Prompt_RateApp_Never", NULL)
                                              otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"LS_Prompt_RateApp_OK", NULL),
                                                                NSLocalizedString(@"LS_Prompt_RateApp_Cancel", NULL),
                              nil];
```

I have screenshots but it won't let me due to being a new account so here's a text version:

```
    [ TITLE LINE 1 ]
    [              ] ( message is clipped )
    [ Button #1    ]
    [ Button #2    ]
    [              ]
    [ Button Cancel]
```

[image]

to:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"LS_Prompt_RateApp_Prompt", NULL)
                                                        message:NULL
                                                       delegate:self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"LS_Prompt_RateApp_Never", NULL)
                                              otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"LS_Prompt_RateApp_OK", NULL),
                                                                NSLocalizedString(@"LS_Prompt_RateApp_Cancel", NULL),
                              nil];
```

I have screenshots but it won't let me due to being a new account so here's a text version:

```
[ TITLE LINE 1 ]
[ TITLE LINE 2 ] ( message == NULL )
[ Button #1    ]
[ Button #2    ]
[              ]
[ Button Cancel]
```

[image]