# UIAlertView in landscape mode does not display message

Tags: uialertview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UIAlertView not showing message text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8868939/uialertview-not-showing-message-text)

I am trying to create a simple UIAlertView for an app in landscape mode but all I see is the title and buttons but no actual message.

It has something to do with the space available for the UIAlertView on the screen as if I remove a couple of the buttons then the message displays fine.

Is there a way to force the UIAlertView to resize itself to fit?

Relevant code is here

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Free Update",nil) 
                                                message:NSLocalizedString(@"There is a new version of this app available in the App Store. Download it now.",nil) 
                                               delegate:self 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Don't remind me",nil)
                                      otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"Download",nil), NSLocalizedString(@"Remind me later", nil), nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Comment: How about you use an action sheet? It always displays the title and it's meant to be used for taking action. Alert views have so many flaws (not implementation, but design), I'm using them sparingly.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901834/uialertview-with-3-buttons-hides-message-in-landscape-mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we had to drop one of the buttons from the alert view to make it work in landscape mode.

Answer (score 8):

a bit dirty but it works :o) just add a UILabel to the UIAlertView

```
UILabel *messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( alert.frame.origin.x + 10, 16, 260, 70)];
messageLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
messageLabel.text = @"Your message";
messageLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
messageLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
messageLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
messageLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
messageLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
[alert addSubview:messageLabel];
```

another dirty hack to get more space between title and buttons.

```
- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView {
    float moreSpace = 20.0f;

    alertView.frame = CGRectMake(alertView.frame.origin.x, alertView.frame.origin.y - moreSpace
                             ,alertView.frame.size.width, alertView.frame.size.height + moreSpace*2 + 10.0f);

    for ( UIView *view in [alertView subviews] ) {
        if ( (view.class != UILabel.class ) && ( view.class != UIImageView.class ) ) {
            [view setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, moreSpace * 2)];
        }
    }
}
```