# UIAlertView not showing message text

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I am bringing up an UIAlertView that works fine in portrait layout, but when in landscape mode - the message doesn't appear.

It is a standard UIAlertView, with three buttons.

```
UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"one", @"two", nil];
```

I have tried moving the buttons down (according to the height of the message label) and resizing the alert according to the relocated buttons, but the message still doesn't appear, despite there being plenty of room for display.
Setting the UILabel background to some color for debugging shows that it just isn't displayed..

EDIT:

The UILabel *is* there - It's just not being displayed.
In the `willPresentAlertView` method, I can see the UILabel in the NSAlertView's subviews.

Comment: UIAlertView != NSAlert. The former is iOS, the later is Mac OS X.

Comment: @DarkDust: slip of the keyboard. Modified. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIAlertView in landscape mode does not display message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059297/uialertview-in-landscape-mode-does-not-display-message)

Comment: also possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7901834/130230.

Comment: Do the answers in the duplicates help you?

Comment: @Emil: noone has found a real solution, yet. I'll keep trying.

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8503793/973036? It's quite dirt, but It works.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a bug with the layout code for UIAlertView. After fiddling a bit in the debugger I managed to get this workaround:

```
UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"one", @"two", nil];

[alert show];

// for some reason we have alpha 0 for 3 or 4 buttons
[[[alert subviews] objectAtIndex:2] setAlpha:1];
// also, for 3 buttons the height goes to 10 -> proof of concept 'fix'
[[[alert subviews] objectAtIndex:2] setFrame:CGRectMake(12, 45, 260, 24)];

[alert release];
```

This is just a proof of concept. A real workaroung should iterate ober the subviews and fix only labels that have either height to small or alpha==0

Answer (score 1):

Probably you missed:

```
[alert show];
```

Comment: Afaik there is no difference with orientation ... works fine for me in either orientation ...

Comment: The alert is showing up, I can dismiss it with buttons, etc - just no message text.

Comment: Please try it for yourself: with two buttons, the message shows just fine. With three buttons, the message is indeed missing in landscape mode as the button layout doesn't leave enough room for the message.

Answer (score -1):

You can directly use [uialertview](http://rj-iphoneworld.webstarts.com) and create object of it. Then pass title and message and button and also other button.....And call click button method.

//Example

```
UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"The message."
delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"button 1" otherButtonTitles:@"button", nil];
                  [alert show];
                  [alert relaese];


//Then use this method

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
// the user clicked one of the ok/cancel buttons
    if(buttonIndex==0)
     {
       NSLog(@"Ok");
     }
     else
     {
     NSLog(@"cancel");
     }
}
```